# Square root in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, math

I'm pretty new to coding and have just started working with angular. Right now I'm trying to make an easy calculator which calculates the growth factor for a period of exponential growth. My current code is as displayed under:

```js
angular.module('eksponenskalkulator', [])
.controller('kalkController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.p = {};
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example35-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="eksponenskalkulator">
  <div ng-controller="kalkController">
  <form>
    Opprinnelig:
    <input type="text" ng-model="p.opprinnelig" /><br />
    Eksponent:
    <input type="text" ng-model="p.eksponent" /><br />
    Endelig:
    <input type="text" ng-model="p.endelig" /><br />
  </form>
  <pre>Svar = {{100*(p.endelig/p.opprinnelig-1)}}</pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works, but what I need to do is to take the seventh root of `(p.endelig/p.opprinnelig)`. I would be very grateful on any ideas on how to do this.

Comment: A root is written in the form n√x. Square roots are generally just written √x, and cube roots as 3√x. You can also write them as a fractional power so that the square root of 10 can be written 10^0.5 or 10^1/2 and the cube root as 10^0.33333 or 10^1/3. 

So basically use fractional powers if i recall math lessons

Comment: And I can do this inside of the angular expression in the <pre> tag?

Comment: of course you can http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp use the Pow function of javascript or the simular one angular js has

Comment: Check the answere below tjespe :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a native [javascript `Math` library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) for common mathematical operations.

For your example, in getting the 7th root, you could use the `Math.pow` function like so:

```
Math.pow(p.endelig/p.opprinnelig,1/7)
```

Comment: exactly what i'm saying!

Comment: okay, but how do I immediately and automatically call this function? @zacran

Comment: @tjespe, I'd make a function in your controller: `$scope.findSeventhRoot(x) { return Math.pow(x, 1/7); }` then update your html like so: `{{100*(p.findSeventhRoot(p.endelig/p.opprinnelig) - 1)}}`

Comment: Sounds very reasonable, I'll se if I can get that to work.

Comment: For some reason, I now only see the angular expression as this: {{100*(p.findSeventhRoot(p.endelig/p.opprinnelig) - 1)}}. Not as a calculated number. I guess something is wrong with how I put the findSeventhRoot in app.js:
`angular.module('eksponenskalkulator', [])
.controller('kalkController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.p = {};
  $scope.findSeventhRoot(x); {return Math.pow(x, 1/7)}
}]);`

Comment: @tjespe The function in your expression isn't attached to `$scope.p` so it should read: `{{100*(findSeventhRoot(p.endelig/p.opprinnelig) - 1)}}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working snippet to show you zacran's answer:

```js
angular.module('eksponenskalkulator', [])
  .controller('kalkController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.p = {
        opprinnelig: 0,
        eksponent: 0,
        endelig: 0
      };
      $scope.findSeventhRoot = function(x) {
        return Math.pow(x, 1 / 7);
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example35-production</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="eksponenskalkulator">
  <div ng-controller="kalkController">
    <form>
      Opprinnelig:
      <input type="number" ng-model="p.opprinnelig" />
      <br />Eksponent:
      <input type="number" ng-model="p.eksponent" />
      <br />Endelig:
      <input type="number" ng-model="p.endelig" />
      <br />
    </form>
    <pre>Svar = {{100*(findSeventhRoot(p.endelig/p.opprinnelig)-1)}}</pre>
  </div>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Everything works fine now. I'm very grateful.

Comment: @tjespe I am glad I was able to help and I appreciate you accepting my answer but can you please change your accepted vote to zacran's answer below.